# Mapping Substrings from dataframe to return values as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, substring, partial

If I have a postal code column, I want to be able to associate substrings of each row to certain Regions. I thought about using a dictionary

dict = { 'SW1': 'London','NE':'London','W1A':'Other','CT':'Other'}

```
Postal Code  
SW1E 5Z
NE99 1AR
SW1
W1A 1ER
CT21 4JF
```

Desired table:

```
Postal Code   Region
SW1E 5Z       London
NE99 1AR      London
SW1           London
W1A 1ER       Other
CT21 4JF      Other
```

However, I don't know how to parse through substrings of a column to create the region column using python (pandas). Please advise on syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) based on the dictionary keys and map them back to create a new column.

```
df['Region']=(df['Postal Code'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(mydict.keys())+')',expand=False)
                                                                           .map(mydict))
print(df)
```

---

```
  Postal Code  Region
0     SW1E 5Z  London
1    NE99 1AR  London
2         SW1  London
3     W1A 1ER   Other
4    CT21 4JF   Other
```

Note I have renamed `dict` to `mydict` since `dict` is a builtin variable and will override the behaviour of a dictionary if stored as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find city easily by a `lambda` fucntion:

```py
dict_ = {'SW1': 'London','NE':'London','W1A':'Other','CT':'Other'}

firstpostal = 'SW1E'
secondpostal = 'abc'

findcountry = lambda postal: [dict_[i] for i in dict_.keys() if i in postal]


print(findcountry(firstpostal))
print(findcountry(secondpostal))
```

and the output:

```
['London']
[]
```

You can check the output list if the city is found or not.